# Code-Changes behind Links. What exactly to do?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

Usually I am not here that much, but more on CodeReview. There yesterday a question showed up, that is now deleted:

> Can any one help me to review the code and help me to fix the issue I am facing ?
>
> Kindly check my post in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057652/an-issue-in-getting-tinymice-rich-text-editor-content-to-struts-action-methods) and do read the comments for better understanding of the problem I am facing.
>
> and find the code in the [google drive link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxDQP8DqOYBcanJ6Z3VNVGt1V00/edit) Let me know where exactly I should change to fix the issue ?
>
> Thank you.

Anyone who knows the Help Center of codereview will see that the question is blatantly off topic. But that is not the point here.

Instead I want to direct your attention to the [SO-Post behind the link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057652/an-issue-in-getting-tinymice-rich-text-editor-content-to-struts-action-methods)

In the comments there, OP refers all others to the google-drive link:

> @DaveNewton kindly use the updated code from below link [drive.google.com/file/d/0BxDQP8DqOYBcanJ6Z3VNVGt1V00/…](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxDQP8DqOYBcanJ6Z3VNVGt1V00/edit)

This link is the exact same as the one in the CodeReview question. But that's just trivia. The underlying problem is: The code in the question here on SO, and the code "in question" are different.

Now I know what the directive for that is on CR:

> If there were no answers yet, It is okay to update your code. If there were answers, your code must not be changed. Any changes are subject to rollback.

I don't know what the "directive" is on SO, but I figure it's important to have a shared understanding on **what code is broken.**

The code seems to have the same problems and edits are possibly minor, **but** should we allow OP to refer users to code behind a link. And the whole thing in an ephemeral comment?
**Definitely not.**

How do I as user make clear to OP that comments are ephemeral, and that the code in the question should be the exact code that he's working on (or at least an SSCCE of it)?

Should I edit the question?
Or should I comment?

And If OP were to not respond to or act upon a comment, what is the next step?

Flagging and/or Downvoting? Or rather edit and try to salvage the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions that don't include the code they want reviewed or the relevant code causing the issue ***in the question itself*** should be closed.

I vote to close those as ***unclear what you're asking*** or ***Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.***

If you don't have close votes yet, just flag them as above.

---

If you want to be extra helpful, you can simply leave a comment explaining to the OP that they need to include the actual code in the question itself. A link can go dead, which could render the whole thread useless. And people don't like to have to go to another page to understand what the issues and solutions are.

I have seen some people that go to the link provided and edit the code into the question themselves. However, I don't personally do this, as it's not my code/(intellectual property) to be posting on the site.