# When recommend an appropriate site for off-topic question?

Tags: discussion, comments, scope

I have tried to answer on the question [An issue in getting tinymice rich text editor content to Struts action methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057652/an-issue-in-getting-tinymice-rich-text-editor-content-to-struts-action-methods), but I got a dilemma on discussion while negotiating the comments.

OP has posted a link on his/her google drive and asked for **Can you check ma code given in above comment ?** I was confused how to proceed further, and suggested to share the code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Then someone from Code Review has offended my comment, because the post is off-topic on Code Review. Should I mark his comment as offensive?

I have voted to close a question as off-topic on SO. But I was told that I did something wrong by recommending a Code Review site because the question is off-topic on Code Review and not for migration.

I didn't intend the question to migrate, but I didn't like to find bugs in someones not working code. I don't really know if it's working or not because it's shared on the google drive. What I did wrong?

Because offender of my comment likes to go endless discussion that I shouldn't suggest a Code Review site for sharing project code. Please, suggest a solution to this problem.

Comment: I personally only comment with something like *it might fit on cr.se but check their on-topic page in the help-center first to be sure and when in doubt ask first on their meta*.  Don't migrate crap is the golden rule...

Comment: The main-question was already subject to another meta-post (by me). See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268609/code-changes-behind-links-what-exactly-to-do for more information.

Comment: additionally closely related: [Be careful when recommending code-review to askers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)

Comment: "I didn't like to find bugs in someones not working code." --> then stop looking at the question and move on. Finding bugs in code is not off-topic on Stack Overflow, even if this particular question wasn't well written or reasonably scoped.

Comment: @Wooble Read further, the code is not posted on SO but shared somewhere for download. It's not github, sourceforge, fiddle, pastebin, googlecode where I can see the source code. Even if the code is not for review then googledrive is not the place for code sharing, and SO require to post relevant code to the question, so ppl can resolve their bugs on site and not downloading someones spaghetti code and check them for viruses, resolve other not related environment problems and so on.

Comment: *the code is not posted on SO*. Then vote to close the question as off-topic, for the reason that *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. * (taken verbatim from the [SO help center on-topic page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), item #1 in the numbered list). Posts at both SO and CR must include the relevant code in the question; SO can't debug non-visible code, and CR can't review it either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every Stack Exchange site (`site`) has Help Center pages:

- **Welcome to …**
  `http://site.stackexchange.com/tour`
  (the first paragraph below the site icon, and the “Ask about…” and “Dont't ask about…” boxes further down)
- **What topics can I ask about here?**
  `http://site.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic`
- **What types of questions should I avoid asking?**
  `http://site.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask`

Unless you are positive that you have read and understood these pages, it is safer to abstain of recommending the site. Keep in mind that these pages are sometimes updated, so it's also safer to re-check them prior to recommending the site.

It also wouldn't hurt to drop into the site's chat and ask regulars whether questions like the one you want to recommend would be okay there.

If that sounds like too much work it's better to abstain from recommending the site at all.

- <sup>Or, if you don't mind playing russian roulette with chances for [flag suspension](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/flag-suspension/info), just flag for moderator to consider migration. I wrote *russian roulette* because when one doesn't take effort to study said pages, there is a good chance for flag to be declined.</sup>

Recommending an asker to a site when one is not well familiar with it tends to do more harm than good. Inexperienced users often simply repost their questions as-is and get frustrated when it turns out off-topic, closed, and voted down.

See also: [What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)

> You're on Stack Overflow and you've found a question that isn't about coding. It's about design or something squishy like that. You are trying to be helpful, and you put a comment in the question... why do they get so annoyed at these suggestions...

---

Speaking specifically about CodeReview.SE, their version of [help/on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page is most definitely worth checking because of fantastic "six yes" check list that helps a lot to understand what their site is about:

> Simply ask yourself the following questions. To be on-topic the answer must be "yes" to all questions:
>
> - Is code included directly in my question? (See *Make sure you include your code in your question* below.)
> - Am I an owner or maintainer of the code?
> - Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?
> - Do I want the code to be good code? (i.e. not code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar)
> - To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?
> - Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?
>
> If you answered "yes" to all the above questions, your question is **on-topic** for Code Review...

<sub>Incidentally, I learned about above when I made the same mistake as you did, recommended CR.SE for a question that didn't match. One of their regulars was kind enough to refer me there (if memory serves they also dropped a few *f-words* when pointing it but after reading that list I kinda understood why).</sub>

Comment: These questions OP should ask if needed to share the project code on CR, if #1 is "yes". OP should read and ask himself all these questions, the post **was not recommended**. It was just friendly suggestion, it is just an adequate reaction to debug someones project code. If OP created a question that comply all these rules then no issue from CR site. Why they posted their comments some question they f-word to the post because was linked and to my name. The post *is not* migrated, if it was then f-word to who has migrated it. I think you should differentiate *recommend* and *suggest* words.

Comment: @RomanC I know what you mean, and there was a time when I believed myself that askers are able to differentiate. But after I discovered that 99% of them interpret "take a look at `site`" as "go there and repost", I totally dropped that. Now I prefer black'n'white. If I'm 100% positive that it will fit, I flag for moderator to migrate. Otherwise I abstain of recommending any particular site (sometimes referring asker to [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773) - again, without mentioning any specific site)

Comment: The black'n'white approach sounds great! Thanks.

Comment: Note that flag weight is long dead; the section about it hasn't been applicable for a number of years now.

Comment: @Servy those who fall into [meta-tag:flag-suspension] may think differently

Comment: @gnat Then they'd be wrong.  That you can be banned from flagging for a sufficient number of declined flags is an entirely separate feature from flag weight.  Flag weight, before it was removed many years ago, was purely a means of ordering flags in the flag queue based on the entire flagging history of the flagger.  Now the order of flags in the queue has nothing to do with the flagger and users can be banned from flagging if their very recent history is sufficiently bad.  Completely different things.

Comment: @Servy [answer was edited](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/268722/revisions) to clarify what I mean here

Comment: related: [Is there something we can do against “Ask this on xyz.SE” comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140491/165773) (at MSE)

Answer (score 9):

The solution is to drop it, and to consider more carefully what questions are appropriate for the target site before making suggestions in future. Flagging their comments as offensive seems wrong to me; being told that you're incorrect is not offensive by any reasonable standard, and the language used isn't offensive - the tone gets a little annoyed nearer the end but that's kind of understandable.

It seems (to me) that you either misunderstood the question, misunderstood the purpose of code review, or both. You said to post it on code review, you were told - by somebody with a not inconsiderable amount of reputation and activity on that site - that code review isn't the correct place for the question. It should have ended there, there shouldn't have been a need to continue debating it in comments.

Comment: How could I know what question is on Code Review? I didn't recommend to migrate the question. If I did I would vote to close with option Other and leaved comment to a moderator. Comments of Vogel612 are offensive because he accuses me that I'm guilty of that recommended this matter to Code Review. I didn't post any Code Review questions, so I could  misunderstood the purpose of code review but _I did not recommend_ the post to code review. I said there's a Code Review where you could post your code for review. I didn't start debating I was just offended.

Comment: @RomanC You said "If you want someone review the code you can post it on Code Review" Regardless of your actual intention, that does sound very much like you're recommending he post his question on Code Review instead. And he doesn't want somebody to *review* his code, he wants somebody to *debug* it - that's not what CR is for; their help center quite clearly states it's for questions on **working** code, and there are enough keywords in the question to indicate that it isn't working: problem, issue, error, etc.

Comment: If you think someone wants to debug the code, that I even don't want to see, then you may be right, but why someone from CR comment to me on SO about *I recommended the post to CR* I didn't. How it sound it's IMO what is in mind. I would try to correct the situation but got following offensive comments.

Answer (score 1):

Short preamble:

> but I didn't like to find bugs in someones not working code.

Stealing Anthony's excellent comment here:

> If you provide the code, an accurate problem statement, and a sufficient explanation of what you expect it to do, then that's an on topic question. If you don't like answering those questions then that's fine, don't answer them - but debugging questions are allowed, provided they meet certain quality standards.

--> Move on then, the question is on topic, if it meets the qualitiy standard. If it doesn't VTC / flag / downvote and move on then ;)

---

There's been quite a few discussions about migrations. You could look them up by searching, too. I will summarize in short what I know.

Especially for comments suggesting "post to codereview", you might want to check [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265629/why-were-comments-suggesting-a-move-to-code-review-removed/265635#265635) on a related post, as well as [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)

Additionally as mentioned in a comment. "The golden rule of migration is: *don't migrate crap*." Migrate here **includes** comments such as yours. (as for why, check the previously linked answer).

So. What is crap and how can I spot it?

The [third comment you posted to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057652/an-issue-in-getting-tinymice-rich-text-editor-content-to-struts-action-methods?noredirect=1#comment39401308_25057652) shows exactly what it is:

> I'm not recommended to migrate this question. OP if he/she want to share the project code which is **off-topic on SO** should make his/her best to present this code project on the appropriate place. SO is not the place for **vague, incomplete, opinion-based, not programming or without understanding problem area, without attempts to solve a problem, asking for finding something, not reproducible errors questions and other.**
>   <sub>Highlighting by me</sub>

As soon as you see such a post the appropriate action to take would have been a combination of the following:

- Flag / Vote To Close (unclear what you're asking, missing context, whatever applies)
- Downvote
- Comment (if you want to)

Comments suggesting: "Post somewhere else", without **exactly knowing** it's a post that is **welcome wherever you recommend it to be posted to** are:

1. Not Helpful (increase moderation cost)
2. Incorrect (it's not okay to post somewhere else)

---

On a sidenote, the first comment was nowhere near offensive IMO, but the following comments may have gotten a bit out of hand. I would like to apologize for that.

Comment: I don't agree that the whole point of SO is finding errors, including bugs. The point is to ask a question why a particular behavior of code is observed while you expect, based on documentation or other side-effects, a different outcome. I'm not a debugging service now, never have been and never will be.

Comment: @rene In what way is what you describe not included in "errors encountered when coding"? Feel free to edit that in or suggest a better wording. (my examples are crap I know, suggest better ones ;))

Comment: @rene you are very welcome to improve that part. Here's kinda where my SO-knowledge and english knowledge leaves me. I no way I wanted to suggest that SO is a code-dump-debugging service (because it isn't). I want to emphasize, that CR isn't either, though ;)

Comment: @rene I don't think that's what he was trying to say. But to say that no questions that ask for help with debugging code are on topic for SO is incorrect. If you provide the code, an accurate problem statement, and a sufficient explanation of what you *expect* it to do, then that's an on topic question. If you don't like answering those questions then that's fine, don't answer them - but debugging questions **are** allowed, provided they meet certain quality standards.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist that is the nuance I was looking for. I can agree with your point of view.