# In the automated closing message, should it mention the existence of alternative SE sites when a question is closed for seeking recommendations?

Tags: discussion, recommendation-questions

**Disclaimer:**
This question is not about what is the appropriate response to take as an individual when a question is seeking recommendations or is off-topic like [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268622/when-recommend-an-appropriate-site-for-off-topic-question?noredirect=1&lq=1). It's a question about what content should be in the automated closing message at that appears at the top of a closed question.

Currently, the closing reason at the top of a question closed for seeking recommendations is the following:

[image]

> Closed. This question is seeking recommendations for books, tools,
> software libraries, and more. It does not meet [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).
> It is not currently accepting answers.
>
> We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools,
> software libraries, and more. You can edit the question so it can be
> answered with facts and citations.

<sup>Taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584135/is-there-a-library-to-parse-numbers-in-r)</sup>

This doesn't give any alternative options to the user if they are actually looking for recommendations and can be perceived as unwelcoming especially since those questions are more likely to come from new users.

So, should there be a mention of alternative sites (such as the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)) to provide an alternative to the user for their question? Something like:

> [...] You can edit the question so it can be answered with facts and
> citations or ask your question on a Stack Exchange site that allows
> questions seeking suggestions (such as [Software Recommendations Stack
> Exchange site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/),  ...)

**The first PROS and CONS that I see:**

**PROS:**

- Gives an alternative for the user
- Allows Software Recs to get some more visibility

**CONS:**

- Might redirect poor quality questions to Software Recs
- The message won't be helpful for all types of recommendations

While writing this question, I noticed that the mention of [Super User was recently removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277872/remove-the-mention-of-super-user-from-the-standard-off-topic-close-reasons) from the "off-topic" close reason, which could suggest that we should avoid mentioning other SE sites inside closing reasons. However, one could still argue that it was right to have the mention at the time when it was introduced.

Alternatively, we could always have a formulation that doesn't refer to a specific SE site, but at least mentions that they do exist in general. Basically, something like above, but without the last part:

> [...] You can edit the question so it can be answered with facts and
> citations or ask your question on a Stack Exchange site that allows
> questions seeking suggestions.

**At least this would tell people that this kind of SE site exists which a lot of people (including me until recently) don't know.**

---

<sup>Note: This question is in part inspired by this [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question#comment900709_254393), but I thought it was worth its own question.</sup>

Comment: 99% of Stack Overflow users (and I among them) are hardly able to correctly determine whether some question is suited for Software Recs. But I am sure that 99% software recommendation questions on Stack Overflow are suited for none of SE sites. For all that 99% users and 99% questions the notion of Software Recs in the close message would cause only a harm. Would a question from other 1% be visited by a user from other 1%, that user would be able to write a more detailed comment about porting a question to the better site.

Comment: You also need to ask folks over at Software Recs (or whichever site) if they want their site to be mentioned at all, if ever this gets implemented. Because "*Might redirect poor quality questions*" is a big disadvantage.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think your comment would be better as an answer.

Comment: @GinoMempin That's fair, but I'm not sure how I should proceed. Tag the moderators in the comments? Post on Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: @DecimalTurn No, MSE isn't the appropriate site (except for Stack Apps, which doesn't have its own meta site). If you're going to post such a question, rather than first ask privately to get a feel for what the site mods would want, then it should be on the meta site associated with the proposed target site.

Comment: [*golden rule*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446) applies.

Comment: I find it funny that you only created an account on software recommendations today and now already use it as an example target site for migrations.

Comment: CONS: [Code Review doesn't want it](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/what-questions-are-suitable-for-migration-to-code-review-and-how-does-the-proce/1688#1688)

Comment: @rene You must have misunderstood my question. This question is not about migrating questions. It's just about listing the possibilities for the user when their question is closed. I even suggest an option not to mention any specific site at the end, but maybe I should have put that more at the top...

Comment: @DecimalTurn and did you check with those sites first that they are OK with being mentioned?

Comment: @RobertLongson I didn’t since I was under the assumption that members of these communities are also present on meta.so, but I've realised that this was probably not the right assumption to make. If I could go back, I would do it differently, but seeing that there isn’t support here for changing the closing message, I’m not sure it’s worth mentioning it now.

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to come at this from a different angle, because your suggestion assumes that we're meant to answer every question and help every person.

**It's not our obligation to determine if someone's question is an ideal fit on another site *without an official migration path.***

Basically, if someone asks a question that's not fit for this site, you moderate it and/or close it per the rules of this site. You don't put extra burden on anyone by asking them to consider the rules or norms of any other site.

Did someone ask for a recommendation? We don't answer those, and I'm not about to figure out on the OP's behalf where they might get an answer. I'm going to tell them instead that this kind of question isn't permitted here and behave accordingly. If that means I catch extra flak for "being unwelcoming", *whatever* with that nonsense already, [I don't really care that much about how they view me anymore.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386324/1079354)

Only moderate questions based on the policies of the site you're on. Vote to migrate if you're willing to swear on whatever you hold sacred in your life that this question 100% absolutely belongs on a site with a valid migration path.

But other than that? It's simply not scalable and it'll make the problem a whole lot worse rather than better.

Comment: FWIW, I don't believe that we should answer every question, but I don't believe that the closing message could be more exhaustive, because it gives the impression that there is no other options. Also, my last suggestion at the bottom doesn't mention any specific SE site. It just suggests that they exist. Closing messages are automated and generic, so I don't see the scalability issue there.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you would only propose someone to post/migrate the question as-is to another site if:

- You are familiar with the scope and rules of the other site.
- The question is on-topic there without radical changes.
- There are no other problems with the question that need to be addressed by the OP, such as lacking information or details.

It is often better to close the question and leave a comment "This question would be better off at site x, but make sure you check what's on-topic there before posting." Sometimes I redirect them with no with the URL to the main site, but to the help/on-topic, for example: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

You can also tell them in comments what would be required to make the question on-topic there, for example: "This is off-topic, it belongs on Electrical Engineering. But in order for the question to be on-topic there, please also provide the schematic."